# If statement with multiple conditions in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to construct an `if` statement with multiple conditions without being too verbose. Currently I have:

```
my $string = "Hamburger";
my @string_as_array = ( $string =~ m/.../g );
my $x=(scalar @string_as_array);
for(my $i=0; $i<$x; $i++)   {
    if ($string_as_array[$i] eq "Ham" || $string_as_array[$i] eq "bur") {
        print "CHEESE";
    }
    elsif ($string_as_array[$i] eq "ger")   {
        print "WICH";
    }
    else {
        print $string_as_array[$i];
    }
}
print "\n";
```

Ideally I'd like something like this for the first `if` statement if it is possible:

```
my $string = "Hamburger";
my @string_as_array = ( $string =~ m/.../g );
my $x=(scalar @string_as_array);
for(my $i=0; $i<$x; $i++)   {
    if ($string_as_array[$i] eq "Ham" || "bur") {
        print "CHEESE";
    }
    elsif ($string_as_array[$i] eq "ger")   {
        print "WICH";
    }
    else {
        print $string_as_array[$i];
    }
}
print "\n";
```

If it's possible.

Comment: This works well thanks! I figured there would be a way to this without grep but this is probably the simplest solution I could find

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my %map = (
   'Ham' => 'CHEESE',
   'bur' => 'CHEESE',
   'ger' => 'WICH',
);

say $string =~ s{...}{ $map{$&} // $& }serg;
```

---

Other things are much more badly in need simplifying!

The symbol soup

```
my $x=(scalar @string_as_array);
for (my $i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
```

simplifies to

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@string_as_array; $i++)
```

which simplifies to

```
for my $i (0 .. $#string_as_array)
```

But you don't actually need the index (just the elements), so replace that with

```
for my $part (@string_as_array)
```

or even

```
for my $part ( $string =~ /.../sg )
```

That already gives us something cleaner:

```
for my $part ( $string =~ /.../sg ) {
    if ($part eq "Ham" || $part eq "bur") {
        print "CHEESE";
    }
    elsif ($part eq "ger")   {
        print "WICH";
    }
    else {
        print $part;
    }
}
```

That said, what we now have begs for a hash lookup.

```
my %map = (
   'Ham' => 'CHEESE',
   'bur' => 'CHEESE',
   'ger' => 'WICH',
);

for my $part ( $string =~ /.../sg ) {
    print $map{$part} // $part;
}

print("\n");
```

We could use a while loop instead.

```
while ( $string =~ /.../sg ) {
    print $map{$&} // $&;
}

print("\n");
```

We could even switch to a substitution operator.

```
say $string =~ s{...}{ $map{$&} // $& }serg;
```

Comment: If I have multiple keys pointing to the same value `'Ham'` and `'bur'` for instance in this case is there a way to combine them on the same line? I am curious because I have 30-40 3 letter keys pointing to the same value.

Comment: Replace `'Ham' => 'CHEESE', 'bur' => 'CHEESE'` with `( map { $_ => 'CHEESE' } qw( Ham bur ) )`

Comment: Hi ikegami, it is amazing to see a piece of 15-line of code get transformed, and eventually become a one-line only solution! Bravo!! Could you explain a bit more on `{ $map{$1} // $1 }` please? I never see such usage of `map // else` before (just saw `map : x` recently). thx.

Comment: @xpt, It's not `map` the operator, it's a hash named `%map`. See the very first snippet for the complete solution, which includes the hash.

Comment: OK, let me ask this way, what does `x // y` means? thx

Comment: @xpt, Symbolic ops are documented in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop). Basically, `defined(x) ? x : y`, except `x` is only evaluated once.

Comment: Gotcha. It is called _"Logical Defined-Or"_ https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Logical-Defined-Or

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with regular expression alternation.

```
if ($string_as_array[$i] =~ /^(?:Ham|bur)$/) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`||`, `&&`, `or`, and `and` are all binary operators, meaning they require two operands. Instead you can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) which accepts a list of things and filters them by some predicate expression:

```
if ( grep { $string_as_array[$i] eq $_ } qw(Ham bur) ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'd use `List::Util::any { $string_as_array[$1] eq $_ } qw(Ham bur)` instead if only to get the short-circuiting. However, hashes are probably better in this particular case.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems perfectly reasonable

Comment: @Tanktalus definitely agree, the short circuiting would be nice